# Matplotlib Error: "figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout"

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, osx-elcapitan

After adding

```
bbox_inches="tight"
```

to an invocation of `plt.savefig` that has worked for several years, I get

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py:1744: UserWarning:
>
> This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so its results might be incorrect

The figure in question appears to work (without [truncation of annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29901422/656912) now), but I wonder what this error could mean and whether there's anything obvious or known (without digging deep into complex figure code) that I can do to address it.

Is there some known or common cause for this that I should look for in my code?

Comment: could you add the code you are using to generate the graph? I just had a look around it it appears to be an issues with adding additional axis or hidden axis linked to colorbars

Comment: You could have a look at [Position colorbar inside figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211967/position-colorbar-inside-figure) thread which is about a similar issue faced with plotting colorbars along with subplots. This warning occurs if you have axes in your plots that aren't subplots. Eg: colorbar axis. The colorbar axis gets overlapped alongwith one of the subplots while rendering as a result.

Answer (score 42):

In my experience, `plt.tight_layout` doesn't always work but `plt.savefig('fig.png',bbox_inches='tight')` does.  In addition, you don't need the former after using the latter and I have come to the conclusion after some pretty extensive testing of it.

Comment: This is the approach I have taken, however I still get the same UserWarning.

Comment: For me, it doesn't work either.