# UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so results might be incorrect. after plt.show

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use matplotlib subplots (where one of the subplots is a table),

and after `plt.show()` I get this warning:

```
UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so results might be incorrect.
```

I have tried to fix it in a few ways without success.

Here is one of the solutions I tried:

```
fig.set_tight_layout(False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: It is only a warning so it begs the question: are the results incorrect as it warns?

Comment: The results are correct

Comment: So you just want to get rid of the warning?

Comment: yes, I don`t want just to ignore it...

Comment: Somehow  `tight_layout` is active, which is not the case by default. Did you activate it yourself? Then the solution is to remove that command. Else, one would need to see a [mcve].

Comment: I got actual incorrect figure alignment following this warning; so is there an answer to the question regarding the underlying reasons behind the warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib Error: "figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight\_layout"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393863/matplotlib-error-figure-includes-axes-that-are-not-compatible-with-tight-layou)