# Why is picture annotation cropped when displaying or saving figure?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have been working at producing some boxplots that include an image that shows what the parts of boxplots represent. As shown in the top right here. This is fine.

[image: with legend]

But, if I remove the green dashed line, which removes the legend, then the little boxplot image is cropped out when I view the plot in jupyter, but also if I save it as image file.e.g.
[image]

The solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901422/matplotlib-with-annotation-cut-off-from-the-saved-figure) using 'tight' doesn't work, i.e.:

```py
plt.savefig("test1.jpg", dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
```

Nor does:

```py
plt.tight_layout()
```

I've also tried using AnnotationBbox but can't find a solution.

Working example code below:

```py
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import (TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage,
                                  AnnotationBbox)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(40, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['Class']=list('ADFADAFDADFAFDAADFAFDAFDDFADFAFDADDFDFAD')


assay=df

factor_to_plot='A'
f=factor_to_plot

x_axis_factor='Class'
g=x_axis_factor

pcntls=assay.groupby([g]).describe(percentiles=[0.05,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95])
sumry= pcntls[f].T
#print sumry
ordered=sorted(assay[g].dropna().unique())

#set figure size and scale text
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(15,10)
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
text_scaling=1.9
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=text_scaling) 

#plot boxplot
ax=sns.boxplot(x=assay[g],y=assay[f],width=0.5,order=ordered, whis=[10,90],data=assay, showfliers=False,color='lightblue', 
            showmeans=True,meanprops={"marker":"x","markersize":12,"markerfacecolor":"white", "markeredgecolor":"black"})


#add dashed line at a value
plt.axhline(0.3, color='green',linestyle='dashed', label="S%=0.3")

#this line sets the scale to logarithmic
#ax.set_yscale('log')

#add legend for dashed line
#plt.legend(markerscale=1.5,loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))

#plt.title("Assay data")

#add gridlines (use for log plots)
plt.grid(True, which='both')


#plot additional percentiles not included in boxplots
ax.scatter(x=sorted(list(sumry.columns.values)),y=sumry.loc['5%'],s=120,color='white',edgecolor='black') 
ax.scatter(x=sorted(list(sumry.columns.values)),y=sumry.loc['95%'],s=120,color='white',edgecolor='black')




#next line is important, select a column that has no blanks or nans as the total items are counted to produce
#N= annotations to plot. 
assay['value']=assay['B']

vals=assay.groupby([g])['value'].count()
j=vals

ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
#print ymax

#put n= values at top of plot    
x=0
for i in range(len(j)):

    plt.text(x = x , y = ymax, s = "N=\n" +str(int(j[i])),horizontalalignment='center')
    #plt.text(x = x , y = 102.75, s = "n=",horizontalalignment='center')
    x+=1


#add legend image
img = plt.imread("legend4.jpg")
plt.figimage(img, 3900,1800, zorder=1, alpha=1)

'''xy = [1.1, 0.8]
fn = "legend4.jpg"
arr_img = plt.imread(fn, format='jpg')

imagebox = OffsetImage(arr_img, zoom=0.2)
imagebox.image.axes = ax

ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy,
                        boxcoords="figure fraction",


                        )

ax.add_artist(ab)'''



#plt.tight_layout()

#use the section below to adjust the y axis lable format to avoid default of 10^1 etc for log scale plots.
#ylabels = ['{:.1f}'.format(y) for y in ax.get_yticks()]
#ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels)

plt.savefig("test1.jpg", dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: It's not cropped, but rather it's not expanded. The figimage is outside the figure and is not taken into account for the `'tight'` option. I would opt for placing it *inside* the figure boundaries

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes it is not perceived as part of the plt.  How come this: https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_annotation_box.html is presented? Can I plot the image in a box outside. My attempts have resulted in errors, but it was getting late....

Comment: Yes you can plot it in a box, but it will still not be shown when using the tight option. For a box the issue would be [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13457). So in any case, you will need to not use the bbox_inches='tight' when saving. Or see [this comment](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12699#issuecomment-435196759) for a workaround.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest okay, thanks, I think I've got it.I didn't realise you built matplotlib!

Answer (score 0):

Using guidance from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have got what I required but in saved plots only, the jupyter inline displays are **still cropped** (not showing annotation box) using the code below:

```py
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import (TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage,
                                  AnnotationBbox)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(40, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['Class']=list('ADFADAFDADFAFDAADFAFDAFDDFADFAFDADDFDFAD')


assay=df

factor_to_plot='A'
f=factor_to_plot

x_axis_factor='Class'
g=x_axis_factor

pcntls=assay.groupby([g]).describe(percentiles=[0.05,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95])
sumry= pcntls[f].T
#print sumry
ordered=sorted(assay[g].dropna().unique())

#set figure size and scale text
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(15,10)
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
text_scaling=1.9
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=text_scaling) 

#plot boxplot
ax=sns.boxplot(x=assay[g],y=assay[f],width=0.5,order=ordered, whis=[10,90],data=assay, showfliers=False,color='lightblue', 
            showmeans=True,meanprops={"marker":"x","markersize":12,"markerfacecolor":"white", "markeredgecolor":"black"})


#add dashed line at a value
#plt.axhline(0.3, color='green',linestyle='dashed', label="S%=0.3")

#this line sets the scale to logarithmic
#ax.set_yscale('log')

#add legend for dashed line
#plt.legend(markerscale=1.5,loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))

#plt.title("Assay data")

#add gridlines (use for log plots)
plt.grid(True, which='both')


#plot additional percentiles not included in boxplots
ax.scatter(x=sorted(list(sumry.columns.values)),y=sumry.loc['5%'],s=120,color='white',edgecolor='black') 
ax.scatter(x=sorted(list(sumry.columns.values)),y=sumry.loc['95%'],s=120,color='white',edgecolor='black')




#next line is important, select a column that has no blanks or nans as the total items are counted to produce
#N= annotations to plot. 
assay['value']=assay['B']

vals=assay.groupby([g])['value'].count()
j=vals

ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
#print ymax

#put n= values at top of plot    
x=0
for i in range(len(j)):

    plt.text(x = x , y = ymax, s = "N=\n" +str(int(j[i])),horizontalalignment='center')

    x+=1


#add legend image

fn = plt.imread("legend4.jpg")
arr_img = fn

imagebox = OffsetImage(arr_img, zoom=0.2)
imagebox.image.axes = ax

ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy=(1.05, 0.5), xycoords="axes fraction",
                                        boxcoords="offset points",
                    pad=0.5

                    )

ax.add_artist(ab)

plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_extra_artists=[a.offsetbox for a in [ab]])
```

I found that I had to delete the 'bbox_inches='tight' part from the final save statement or I found that my 'N=...' text annotations were being cropped. Can't believe it is this hard to do!

gives:

[image: plot with image key]

Comment: To prevent cropping in IPython, you can use `%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs={'bbox_inches':None}` in your jupyter notebook. This will tell the inline backend not to use the `tight` option when creating the png files which are shown in the jupyter output cells.

Comment: It's not obvious but for some reason there is extra white-space on the left of the figure.  I don't know why this has appeared.

Comment: If you don't crop the figure, there will be more whitespace.